# scipy 0.16 and robust regression with implicit ODE

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I do want to fit an implicit ODE to some data and It would be good if I use robust regression. This feature is implemented in scipy 0.17 but it seems that the ODE solver (assimulo package) requires scipy 0.16 ( with scipy 0.17: `anaconda3/envs/scipy0.17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/linalg/../../../../libgfortran.so.3: version 'GFORTRAN_1.4' not found`).

There is a section in the [scipy cookboock](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.org/items/robust_regression.html) dealing with robust regression. It is said, that the residuals and the Jacobian matrix are modified at each timestep. 
So it would not be enough to change  just the residual function ? In which way would I have to change the Jacbian Matrix and can this be done at each timestep using scipy 0.16 ?

Any ideas how I could use either scipy 0.17 with assimulo (maybe by symlinks ) or implement a robust nonlinear fitting method within scipy 0.16 ? Or are there some other optimization packages which would work ?

Comment: You might be interested in this package: http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitting_types.html#ode-fitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems something is broken in the package. From the [issue tracker](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/686):

At least on an Ubuntu machine, following workaround helps: `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3` By this way the problematic version of libgfortran is replaced temporarily.